# Can clients connect to internet from inside without pppoe setting (Juniper srx300)?

Tags: networking, firewall, juniper, juniper-network-connect

I want clients from inside zone to access internet. I searched plenty of times but no compatible solutions. 
My device is Juniper SRX300.
much appreciate for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I am using SRX300 and all inside zone is allowed to access internet. See the answer from [Cannot access internet from clients behind Juniper Firewall SRX300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930662/cannot-access-internet-from-clients-behind-juniper-firewall-srx300)